# Netbeans "no tests executed"

Tags: php, unit-testing, netbeans, phpunit

I have a php project with unit tests included. I use Netbeans for development and would like to have phpunit intergration in my IDE. If I run phpunit from the commandline, it is working. **If I press Alt+F6 to run tests in Netbeans no tests run**, I get the message:

> No tests executed (Perhaps an error occurred, verify in Output window.)

The structure (it is a Zend Framework 2 module):

```
Foo/
  src/
    Foo/
      Bar.php
      Baz.php
  tests/
    Foo/
      BarTest.php
    bootstrap.php
    phpunit.xml
  Module.php
  autoload_register.php
```

Contents of BarTest.php

```
namespace Foo;

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as TestCase;

class BarTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIsWorking ()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

My phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Foo">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

My bootstrap.php:

```
// Set error reporting pretty high
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

// Get base, application and tests path
define('BASE_PATH',  dirname(__DIR__));

// Load autoloader
require_once BASE_PATH . '/autoload_register.php';
```

In the Netbeans project properties I tried:

1. To set the tests directory to `Foo/tests` (this is required I think)
2. To set specifically the bootstrap file (not required I think)
3. To set specifically the XML configuration file (not required I think)
4. To set specifically to run all *Test files (not required I think)

**How can I ensure Netbeans can execute my phpunit tests?**

Comment: Did you try running `phpunit --bootstrap bootstrap.php Foo/tests` ? Because thats what IDE ultimately does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I had set error_reporting to a high level, the PHP CLI did not have display_errors turned on. This was it, so now I got my reporting back...

Comment: Can you explain what this means and how can I do that? I am also getting `Perhaps an error occurred, verify in Output window.` error. I am completely new to PHPUnitTest.

Comment: The bootstrap.php file included `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` but not `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`. So though the errors were reported, they were not displayed. Setting this too showed me the errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you tell me where should I find this bootstrap.php file? I get so many bootstrap.php files in search result and don't know which one should I make change to.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put all of this into your PHPUnit bootstrap.php:

```php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Netbeans expect all tests situated in one root project folder. If it's not done this way, Code Coverage and others features are not working correctly.
See [enhancement](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201654) for more informations.

This problem can be solved creating custom testSuite:

- Create directory "test" or "tests" in your root project folder if it's not created yet.
- Create file TestSuite.php in this "test" folder
- Add this TestSuite.php in your Netbeans project settings.

```php
<?php

class TestSuite extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new TestSuite();

        $file = '/Foo/tests/Foo/BarTest.php';

        echo 'Adding test: ' . $file . "\n";
        $suite->addTestFile($file);

        //add here algorithm that will search and add all test files from your /tests directory

    return $suite;

}
```

Netbeans 7.2 will have nice feature to [run all test in separate directory](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/run_tests_in_folder).

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is not finding the autoloader classes. Then, in the project settings you must say what the class autoloader, bootstrap, etc.

In my case just went in: Project Properties -> Testing -> PHPUnit. 
I set the option to "Use Bootstrap", and told the path of the bootstrap.

My bootstrap file has the autoloader then all my test classes were executed without errors.