# PHP UnitTesting - Perhaps error occurred, verify in Output window

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit, netbeans-8

I am trying to do PHP UnitTesting in Netbeans (Zend Framework 2). When there is no error I can see all the passed methods in the output window. However, when the test has some errors I get this error: "Perhaps error occurred, verify in Output window." I can't see any errors in the output window - No tests executed. Any idea how to solved this problem and find out where the errors occured?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125971/netbeans-no-tests-executed

Comment: It seems netbeans is calling phpunit with --log-junit. If you run the exact same command but remove this argument it seems to work. Not sure how to make netbeans stop doing this though..